# Encode::Guess->guess gives different results to guess_encoding

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I have this script. Somefile.xsd is a file that contains a few UTF-8 chars. I've however found that I can't get `guess_encoding` to report the same encoding as Encode::Guess->guess. Ignoring the fact it's an XSD, what obvious thing (and I'm sure it probably is obvious) am I missing that I haven't done?

```
use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;

open (FILE, "<", "somefile.xsd");

print ("Reading file...\n");
#$text = <FILE>;
while ($text = <FILE>) {
    $encoding1 = Encode::Guess->guess($text);
    if (ref($encoding1)) {
        $name = $encoding1->name;
        print "$name : $text" if ($name ne "ascii");
    } else {
        print ("Not found : $text");
    }

    $encoding2 = guess_encoding($text, qw/iso-8859-15 ascii iso-8859-1 utf8/);
    if (ref($encoding2)) {
        $name = $encoding2->name;
        print "$name : $text" if ($name ne "ascii");
    } else {
        print ("Not found : $text");
    }

}

close(FILE);
```

When I run this, it gives these results:

```
H:\play>perl encoding.pl
Reading file...
utf8 :                  <xs:enumeration value="Bokmål, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokmål"/>
Not found :                     <xs:enumeration value="Bokmål, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokmål"/>
utf8 :                  <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Provenæ ¬"/>
Not found :                     <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Provenæ ¬"/>
utf8 :                  <xs:enumeration value="Volapük"/>
Not found :                     <xs:enumeration value="Volapük"/>
```

**Edited to clarify**: I want to use the version of `guess_encoding` with the second option (i.e., a list of suspects). Removing the list gives me nothing over just calling `Encode::Guess->guess`. The use case is that I want to check a file matches one of a set of encodings, and passing the valid list in seems more elegent than calling guess and looking the name up in a list, especially when I've had `$encoding->name` give me a result of `iso-8859-15 or utf8`, which means I can't simply check for equality against a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the qw:

```
$encoding2 = guess_encoding($text);
```

That should give you the correct answer.

EDIT.

Running this code:

```
use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;

open (FILE, "<", "somefile.xsd");

print ("Reading file...\n");
#$text = <FILE>;
while ($text = <FILE>) {
    $encoding1 = Encode::Guess->guess($text);
    if (ref($encoding1)) {
        $name = $encoding1->name;
        print "$name : $text" if ($name ne "ascii");
    } else {
        print ("Not found : $text");
    }

   $encoding2 = guess_encoding($text, qw/iso-8859-15 ascii iso-8859-1 utf8/);

    if (ref($encoding2)) {
        $name = $encoding2->name;
        print "$name : $text" if ($name ne "ascii");
    } else {
        print ("Not found : $text");
    }

   $encoding3 = guess_encoding($text);

    if (ref($encoding3)) {
        $name = $encoding3->name;
        print "$name : $text" if ($name ne "ascii");
    } else {
        print ("Not found : $text");
    }

    print "-"x40 ."\n";
}

close(FILE);
```

produces:

```
Reading file...
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
----------------------------------------
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Bokm├Ñl, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokm├Ñl"/>
----------------------------------------
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
----------------------------------------
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Occitan (post 1500); Proven├ª ┬¼"/>
----------------------------------------
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
----------------------------------------
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
Not found : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
utf8 : <xs:enumeration value="Volap├╝k"/>
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: So why does guess_encoding fail? The docs say that the second param is the list of suspects that will be tested. I'm listing UTF-8, the encoding is UTF-8, what am I missing? The whole point of providing a suspects list is so that you don't have to try every suspect. In my case, I want to limit the list as I only want specific encodings as I want to handle the others as an error condition - providng a suspect list seemd to be a more elegent way than checking the returned string.